# Why Emacs cannot find hunspell spanish dictionaries?

Tags: hunspell

Here I am on a GNU/Linux machine.

I have installed hunspell 1.7.0-3 and hunspell-es_MX and a lot of the english dictionaries as well.
If I type

```
hunspell -D
```

I get, along others:

```
/usr/share/hunspell/es_MX
```

And if i check the files I can see that I have a aff file in the mentioned directory.
In my .emacs file I have:

```
(setenv
  "DICPATH"
  "/usr/share/hunspell")
;; Tell ispell-mode to use hunspell.
(setq
  ispell-program-name
  "hunspell")

(setq ispell-local-dictionary "es_MX")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
     '(("es_MX" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil nil nil utf-8)))
```

as I saw in other questions here.

But If i run the spell checker it fails, printing:

```
Can't find Hunspell dictionary with a .aff affix file
```

I am completely lost here.

More info:
My Emacs is 27.2
and the output of the command pointed by rplium, `hunspell -D -a /dev/null`,  is:

```
SEARCH PATH:
.::/usr/share/hunspell:/usr/share/myspell:/usr/share/myspell/dicts:/Library/Spelling:/home/karel/.openoffice.org/3/user/wordbook:/home/karel/.openoffice.org2/user/wordbook:/home/karel/.openoffice.org2.0/user/wordbook:/home/karel/Library/Spelling:/opt/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
/usr/share/hunspell/en_SG
/usr/share/hunspell/en_AG
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US
/usr/share/hunspell/en_BS
/usr/share/hunspell/en_GB
/usr/share/hunspell/es_MX
/usr/share/hunspell/en_HK
/usr/share/hunspell/en_NG
/usr/share/hunspell/en_GB-large
/usr/share/hunspell/en_BZ
/usr/share/hunspell/en_ZA
/usr/share/hunspell/en_NZ
/usr/share/hunspell/en_NA
/usr/share/hunspell/en_ZW
/usr/share/hunspell/en_IN
/usr/share/hunspell/en_GH
/usr/share/hunspell/en_JM
/usr/share/hunspell/en_BW
/usr/share/hunspell/en_TT
/usr/share/hunspell/en_DK
/usr/share/hunspell/en_IE
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US-large
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_SG
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_AG
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_US
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_BS
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_GB
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/es_MX
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_HK
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_NG
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_GB-large
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_BZ
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_ZA
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_NZ
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_NA
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_ZW
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_IN
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_GH
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_JM
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_BW
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_TT
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_DK
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_IE
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_US-large
Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "es_ES"
```

Comment: Telling us the version of Emacs helps. What does `hunspell -D -a /dev/null` output?

Comment: Ok. Last line seems to be pointing to something important.

Comment: OK, looks like your default hunspell dictionary is set to 'es_ES', which is not installed. See if `DICTIONARY=es_MX hunspell -D -a /dev/null` lists a `.aff` file (and if so, see if you can change the default dictionary for hunspell to be "es_MX")

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It has to do with something that is not obvious and is not easily found online or on the hunspell entry in the Emacs documentation. The es_MX dictionary (Mexican Spanish) is only a complement of the es_ES or es_any dictionaries, that act as the base. So I needed to put one of these for the es_MX to work.